# stackを使い文字列を逆にする方法で TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str エラーになる

Tags: python

Python初心者です。以下に示したコードに関して、いくつか質問があります。

- `reverse = reverse + stack.pop()` に問題があるようで、以下のエラーが出ます。

  ```
  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
  ```
- なぜ `while stack.size():` で `stack.size()` を使うのでしょうか。
  これは "Hello" の文字数分（5回）繰り返すという意味でしょうか。
  また、`stack.size()` の中身がなくなるまでという意味でしょうか。

---

**対象のコード:**

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

stack = Stack()

for c in "Hello":
    stack.push(c)

reverse = ""

while stack.size():
    reverse = reverse + stack.pop()

print(reverse)
```

Comment: `return` がない事が原因ですね…

Comment: 解決しました。returnが必要なのですね。

Comment: 大変ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

1つ目の回答は`def pop(self):`のreturnが抜けています。
下記の修正で意図通りに動くと予想されます。

修正前: `self.items.pop()`
修正後: `return self.items.pop()`

2つ目の回答は[pop()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)を呼び出すたびに配列の末尾が1つポップしますので、お見込みの通り「stackの中身がなくなって`stack.size()`の戻り値が0になるまで」という解釈で合っています。